# "it is impossible" or "that is impossible"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Tell me please if there is any difference between *it* and *that* in the following context.

> Person 1: Last week I bench-pressed 150 kilos.
>
> Person 2: **It**/**that** is not impossible because the week before you bench-pressed only 135 kilos.

As a non-native speaker I cannot see the difference between *it* and *that*, so please help me see it if there is any.

Comment: In the example sentence you give, either word is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following conversation:

> You know that guy named Dmytro?
>   --The weightlifter?
>   Yeah. He bench-pressed 1000 pounds yesterday.
>   -- That's impossible! It's not possible for a human being to lift so much weight.

**That** refers *back* to what has just been said, that is, to the other person's claim that Dmytro lifted 1000 pounds.  In this conversational context, **that** = *what you said a moment ago*.

**It** refers *forward* to what is being said now by the skeptic; you can understand it like this:

{Something} is not possible!  What is the thing that is not possible?  The impossible something = "for a human being to lift so much weight".

In this conversational context, **it** = *what I am about to say*.